# Organising image uploads for improved performance in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Image uploading is becoming more and more popular on my WordPress site. I currently organise the uploaded files into year and month folders like this: `/uploads/2014/02/file.png`. This is the standard way WordPress does it.

With reference to performance, is there a better way I can organise the uploads? For example, would organising the uploads into more folders (year, month and day folders `/uploads/2014/02/15/file.png`) improve performance (fetching and displaying the image)?

Or would having less folders speed things up `/uploads/2014/file.png`? If so, please explain why.

Please note I could end up with 10,000s of images on my site.

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to keep all 10000 images in one folder. I prefer to organise files into year/month folders.
There is a plugin that can handle the upload filename and directory and change them to whatever you want.

> WordPress allow you to put uploads in year- and month-based folders. Custom Upload Dir is somewhat smarter. You can construct paths from variables like post title, category, post author, post date and many more.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/

Comment: Thanks for answering and thanks for the link. But 'why' is it better?

Comment: Also if you use Windows as a server OS for Wordpress more than 5000 files in one directory can affect performance.